# Iterate code to add hyperlink with excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

[image: table_snpshot]I have code that creates hyperlink in one cell. I want it to iterate through all filled cells along column F or C or E.

```
Sub insertVeryLongHyperlink()

Dim curCell As Range
Dim longHyperlink, TextToDisplay1 As String

Set curCell = Range("G1")  ' or use any cell-reference
longHyperlink = [E1]
TextToDisplay1 = [C1]

curCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=curCell, _
                Address:=longHyperlink, _
                SubAddress:="", _
                ScreenTip:=" - Click here to follow the hyperlink", _
                TextToDisplay:=TextToDisplay1

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean the `hyperlink` is in column E and the `textToDisplay` is in column C and you want to iterate over the columns and add a hyperlink to cells in column G?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I want to create hyperlinks till last row in table. Please find snapshot in main post.

Comment: Enclose your code in `For...Loop` and iterate over all rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This produces hyperlinks in `column G`.

```
Sub InsertVeryLongHyperlink()
    Dim cl As Range

    For Each cl In Range("G1:G" & Range("G1").End(xlDown).Row)
        cl.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=cl, Address:=cl.Offset(0, -2).Text, TextToDisplay:=cl.Offset(0, -4).Text, ScreenTip:=" - Click here to follow the hyperlink"
    Next cl
End Sub
```

- `cl.Offset(0, -2).Text` is column E
- `cl.Offset(0, -4).Text` is column C

Comment: Great but need to change till last row. Right now range is fixed, can you help me to make range variable according to total row count?

Comment: Thanks, it's working great, just made one correction ("F1") instead of ("G1").